# Java - Get data from website doesn't work (403 Error)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that get data from [here](http://www.pccomponentes.com/intel_core_i5_6600_3_3ghz_box.html) but an error appear (403 error)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL urlObject;
        String codigo;
        try{
            urlObject=new URL("http://www.pccomponentes.com/intel_core_i5_6600_3_3ghz_box.html");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(urlObject.openStream());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
            while((codigo=br.readLine())!=null)
                System.out.println(codigo);
                br.close();

        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the program this error appear:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.pccomponentes.com/intel_core_i5_6600_3_3ghz_box.html
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at Test.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

The purpose of the program it's get the price of the product and print it with a System.out.println, how can I do that?

Comment: A 403 Error means your request is being denied by the Server.  It wants you to authenticate first.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" into the title. Accepting the correct answer (which you've done already) is everything you need to do. Changing the title is not necessary or wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested with `curl` it works, but if I set the `User-Agent` used by `Java` by default I get this `403` HTTP error. It seems that the web master of this website doesn't like `Java` :-)

To work around this, simply set another `User-Agent` by doing this:

```
urlObject=new URL("http://www.pccomponentes.com/intel_core_i5_6600_3_3ghz_box.html");
URLConnection c = urlObject.openConnection();
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "<put a the user agent of your choice here>");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream());
```

If you don't know which `User-Agent` to use, use the one of your browser that you can get from [here](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/)

Comment: thanks, It worked! I updated the question, now I want to get only the price! In this case it's €215